# Using a string in two different methods

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have been trying to pass a string value from one method into another. Here are my two methods.

Method 1-

```
public void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var c_id = (e.AddedItems[0] as Foodlist).C_ID;
        string listboxid = c_id.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want the string listboxid value in my second method so that I can use it for comparison.
Method 2-

```
public void deletemyfood()
{
    using (FoodDataContext context = new FoodDataContext(Con_String))
    {
        string listboxindex = listboxid;
        IQueryable<FoodViewModel> foodQuery = from c in context.FoodTable where c.C_ID.ToString() == listboxindex select c;
        ....
    }
}
```

any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: use a *function parameter* ? Any problem with that?

Comment: Surely you have a parameter for "deletemyfood" as string and just pass the string you get from the selection change? although of course it does mean as someone arrows down the listbox, it would delete each set as it went...

Comment: yes I want to pass the selection change string- listboxid

Comment: @Tigran, Maybe he doesn't know how to use method parameters yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a *Simple* example on how you can use return values and parameters:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Method1("Test");
    }

   static string Method1(string input)
   {
       return string.Format("I got this input: {0}", input);
   }
}
```

In this example, the method `Method1` takes a string parameter and then returns a string.

In your case you might want to change the method signature of `DeleteMyFood` to this:

`public void DeleteMyFood(string foodId)`

If you want some sort of result though, too know when the method succeeded or not, you might want to have a value returned from the method as well. This can be done by modifying the method signature once again:

`public bool DeleteMyFood(string foodId)`

If I understand correctly based on your comments, you want to change the event handler to this:

```
public void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                    System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var c_id = (e.AddedItems[0] as Foodlist).C_ID;
        string listboxid = c_id.ToString();
        DeleteMyFood(listboxid);
    }
}
```

This requires that the method `DeleteMyFood` accepts a parameter of type string, so we need to change that as well:

```
public void deletemyfood(string foodId)
{
    using (FoodDataContext context = new FoodDataContext(Con_String))
    {
        string listboxindex = listboxid;
        IQueryable<FoodViewModel> foodQuery = from c in context.FoodTable where c.C_ID.ToString() == foodId select c;
        // .. rest of code here ..
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw something similar in the related posts, but didn't get it. Can you explain using my above example?

Comment: @ShubhamM, Does it make sense now that I've edited it a little bit?

Comment: yes totally. :) the only problem I am getting is "No overload for method 'deletemyfood' takes 0 arguments" on line private void deleteButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                deletemyfood(s);
            }
        }

Comment: @ShubhamM, Ok, that is because you've got a missmatch somewhere else in the code, did you change so that the method `deletemyfood` now looks like what I showed in the code above?

Comment: public void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var c_id = (e.AddedItems[0] as Foodlist).C_ID;
                string listboxid = c_id.ToString();
                deletemyfood(listboxid);
            }
        }

Comment: public void deletemyfood(string listboxid)
        {
            using (FoodDataContext context = new FoodDataContext(Con_String))
            {
                string listboxindex = listboxid;
                IQueryable<FoodViewModel> foodQuery = from c in context.FoodTable where c.C_ID.ToString() == listboxindex select c; }
        }

Comment: they are exactly same as you explained in the example.

Comment: Are you still getting the error? Make sure that you do not have 2 methods called `deletemyfood` and `DeleteMyFood`, you just want one of them!

Comment: yup, I am still getting error. I am having only one method deletemyfood and calling it in deletebutton method.

Comment: @ShubhamM, On all the places that you call `deletemyfood()` you now need to send in a string like this `deletemyfood("id")`, are you doing that in `deletebutton` as well?

Comment: I am not sending any string. What do I send in the deletebutton code? any ideas?

Comment: try this `deletemyfood(listBox1.SelectedItem as Foodlist).C_ID.ToString())`

Comment: works fine as of now. I am building an example app to test my skills. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ShubhamM, No problem! Happy programming :)